# Concatenate all Rows into single string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i need to concatenate all rows to display in a single string 
i wrote the same query for other table it works
**both queries gives me a last row value only**

```
   declare @varaibelName nvarchar(max)
    set @cpx=''
    Select  @varaibelName=COALESCE(@varaibelName,'')+  FeildName From TableName
    select @varaibelName
```

**or**

```
 declare @varaibelName nvarchar(max)
    set @varaibelName=''
    Select  @varaibelName=@varaibelName+ FeildName From TableName  
    select @varaibelName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be because your second to last value is NULL, so it'll effectively set the parameter to NULL, and then fetch the last remaining row.

[See fiddle here for example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37fef/2/0)

To fix that, you can prepare for the null with for example ISNULL, like so (replace the SQL in the fiddle with this, and see what happens):

```
declare @variableName nvarchar(max)
Select  @variableName=COALESCE(@variableName,'')+  ISNULL(FieldName,'') From TableName
select @variableName
```

Better yet, you probably want to separate the columns from each other, so you can do this to add a comma inbetween them, then parse the extra comma off from the end of the string:

```
declare @variableName nvarchar(max)
Select  @variableName=COALESCE(@variableName,'')+  ISNULL(FieldName+', ','') From TableName
select @variableName = SUBSTRING(@variableName, 1, LEN(@variableName)-1)
select @variableName
```

**EDIT:**

HoneyBadger is absolutely right, in his comment below. Since I'm having a brainfart day regarding COALESCE, might as well go with this to avoid pointlessly using both:

```
declare @variableName nvarchar(max) set @variableName = ''
Select  @variableName= @variableName + ISNULL(FieldName+', ','') From TableName
select @variableName = SUBSTRING(@variableName, 1, LEN(@variableName)-1)
select @variableName
```

Comment: Why do you use COALESCE to catch NULL for the variable, and ISNULL to catch NULL for the Fieldname?